# Add trailing zeros to an integer

Tags: shell, append

I need to add `n` trailing zeros to an integer.

**For example:**

```
n=4
y=1
output 10000
```

I used the code below but I need to give an integer value in place of `n` and that should be converted to number of zeros. Any idea?

```
n=00 
y=1 
printf  "%d$n\n" $y
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: It appears to be a shell script.

Comment: it is shell script.

Comment: Did my suggested code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're using (I added the C++ tag just to get you going somewhere and get some views). But you might be best off to create a string (adding a 0 to the end of it for each iteration of the `n` variable). Then you could parse that string back to a number?

Otherwise, you could try multiplying your number by 10 for each `n` iteration.

**Something like..**

```
number = y

for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    number *= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether n is greater than zero:

```
n=4
y=15
if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then
  printf  "$y%0*d\n" $n 0
else
  printf  "$y\n"
fi
```

Comment: You're welcome. FYI %0*d gets two parameters. 0* adds leading zeros to 2nd parameter so that total number of digits equals 1st parameter. Here 1st parameters is n and 2nd is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on hutheano's answer, here is equivalent code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n,y;
  n=4;
  y=1;

  if (n>0)
    printf("%d%0*d\n", y, n, 0);
  else
    printf("%d\n", y);

  return 0;
}
```